# how can I remove very long (falsely accused) std::_Conjunction template errors from my Error List?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I have [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) lookup tables that have 1024 elements and look like this:

```
constexpr auto ln2_mantissa = std::array<std::uint32_t, 1024>{0x651fbb09u, 0xe35dff88u, /* ... */ 0x2168c234u, 0xc90fdaa2u};
```

[`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) calls this compile time check:

```
#if _HAS_CXX17
template <class _First, class... _Rest>
struct _Enforce_same {
    static_assert(conjunction_v<is_same<_First, _Rest>...>,
        "N4687 26.3.7.2 [array.cons]/2: "
        "Requires: (is_same_v<T, U> && ...) is true. Otherwise the program is ill-formed.");
    using type = _First;
};
```

in order to guarantee that all elements inside the `{0x651fbb09u, /* ... */}` are of the same type.

---

Visual Studio tends to always display the full `std::_Conjunction` template chain as an active error whenever I encounter ***any*** build error (even though the error is somewhere else; all types inside the `std::array<>{ ... }` are equal).

```
Error (active)  E1018   class "std::_Conjunction<true, std::is_same<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::is_same<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::is_same<unsigned int, unsigned int>, /* ... */
```

[image: the full std::_Conjunction error List]

this makes it very difficult to see my real build errors as the output above is listed first and multiple times.

It triggers the active errors `E0262`, `E1018` and `E0135`

---

is there a way to exclude these listings from my Error List?

***Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.6.2***

Comment: Can you provide some ways to reproduce? Cannot reproduce error issue [here](https://godbolt.org/z/TcUvVe).

Comment: Are you sure that *all* elements in the initializer are 32-bit values? There's no number that might happen to have a ninth digit? Can you replicate with a smaller data-set? Can you replicated with only a single number using more than 32 bits? If you try to create a plain C-style array (i.e. `uint32_t ln2_mantissa[1024] = { ... }`) what does the compiler tell you then?